# Django - record seemingly vanishing?

Tags: django

I have a fairly complex bit of logic which, as I just discovered, results in a record simply vanishing. I'll try and lay out the code's logic...

- We have around 1,000 clients in our database
- Once a year, we send two letters in order (first one must go out first, then the second one about a month later)
- In order for us to be able to send the letters, a set of about 30 checks and balances need to be checked on each client's information. Things like, "Do we have a record of the clients X", "Do we have information pertaining to client's Y". Just a set of information we need to have on file before we can send the letters.
- For clients who have missing information, I have created a "Staging Area" which show a list of clients with missing information, and what info they are missing.
- Clients will all information (ie: we can send the 1st letter) go into the "Ready for First Letter" area
- At any time, we might loose some information which should cause the client to leave the "Ready for First Letter" area and return to the "Staging Area".
- The user should rectify the situation (add the missing information) to kick the client back into the "Ready for First Letter" area
- After the first letter is send, the clients then go to the "Ready for Second Letter" area. Again, if at any time we loose some information, the client should pop out of the "Ready for Second Letter" area and return to the staging area.

What I'm finding is happening is that a client will be in the "Ready for First Letter" area and then we'll loose some information. The client *should* just move over to the "Stagin Area". However, the record simple vanishes! It seems to be getting deleted and I can't find anywhere in my code the keyword `delete`. I'm kinda confused why this would be happening.

I know it's hard to make any sort of "you're doing it wrong there" type of comments without me posting code, but I don't really know what to post since there is a LOT of code to make this all happen (I'm generalizing a lot of what is happening).

I suppose I'm wondering if there are circumstances where a record might be removed by Django or deleted. Does this happen? Seems crazy if so...

Thanks

*** Edit *** Partial insight:

I think I've located where the mystery is occurring. I have been testing a specific bit of information by removing it from the client's record to see if the client does, in fact, return to the staging area. When I remove this specific information, the client's record disappears too. Here's my code (not copy and pasted, just a re-written idea):

```
c = client.objects.get(pk=1)
tmp = c.specificInfo
tmp.delete()
c.specificInfo = None
c.save()
```

I should point out that `c.specificInfo` is a Foreign Key. So, presumably I was assigning a different record to `tmp` and then deleting that item. Doing so has the side effect of removing `client` too.

Very confusing...

Comment: is there a signal that does some post_delete kind of operations. Also, do you see the record in the django admin interface?

Comment: It was in the admin interface that I watched it dissappear. I was struggling to see where the record was going (maybe I missed it move form the Staging to a "Ready for Letter" area). I would look at it in Admin interface, then intentionally remove some information, then reload the non-admin page and it would disappear. I move back to the admin interface, hit reload and same deal - disappear. I went through all 10 pages of the admin interface to see if it was reordered, but nothing. I'm not aware of any post_delete operations.

Comment: easiest thing to do would be to remember the id of an object that would get "deleted" and go to django `./manage.py shell` and access the object - to know if it is actually getting deleted

Comment: If its not in the admin page, is it not safe to assume its been deleted? I have found out where, in my code, it seems to be happening. I'll post an edit above...

Comment: well.. it is very much possible to override the default admin views. I am just saying it could be a possibility. Very hard to reverse engineer without knowing the actual system

Comment: Ya, I know it's hard to reverse engineer with knowing more details - but it's such a vast amount of code I don't really know what specific sections to post. Thanks for your help though, it has caused me to find a sliver of evidence as to what the problem is (noted in my edit).

Comment: for starters, remove `tmp = c.specificInfo` and `tmp.delete()` equivalent code (just assign the foreign key field to none and save) to see if the problem still occurs, if yes - we are looking at the wrong piece of code

Comment: I can confirm that removing those two lines does, in fact, make the problem go away. Without those two lines my record stays in tact (as it should).

Comment: makes sense - you might have a CASCADE DELETE set somewhere https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects

Comment: This might help you too http://fragmentsofcode.wordpress.com/2009/03/06/django-gotcha-related-objects-deleted-by-default/

Comment: That's what I was thinking too (the cascade delete). But it doesn't really make sense to me. In any event, I'll have to figure out a different way to remove that specific bit of information. Perhaps get the PK, set the client record to `None`, then delete the info record on its own. I'll give that a shot and see.